# Obtaining a hook for when a JPanel's host JFrame closes, without using a Window Closing Event

Tags: java, swing

I realize that the formal way is to listen for a window closing event added to the JFrame host, and then simply call a cleanup method on the JPanel. However, I got curious. I only recently acquired the need for a shutdown (closing, leaving, going away now) hook in my Panel that's already in use in my program. And, out of curiosity, I didn't want to go revisit the places where this panel gets placed into a generic old JFrame (one with no special handling required) and where it just gets shown as a dialog, waiting for input, to then be dismissed after. I didn't want to make this hypothetical other coder (me) go add window listeners to those frames that already use my panel, requiring them to now call a new shutdown method. It's my code in the Panel that needs the added ability, so why make those Framers all go change their code to add window listeners? Can't a JPanel find this out for itself?

So, I made a hack for the JPanel to detect when it's being closed without the JFrame needing a window listener. The JPanel, to me, is more self aware now ... it has a window closing detection tactic of it's own, independent of the coder using my JPanel needing to write listeners and call shutdown hooks. I just wanted to try and do it without having to go back and change existing code.

Realize too, that my hack only works with DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, but ... that's what I was using for my dialog anyway.

Can somebody show me how I should do this then? Is there a property event I could dig for? This has to be a fire-able offense what I've just done here. It has to be very wrong. Yet, I have my self aware JPanel shutdown hook, and it works. Someone please steer me elsewhere (without the obvious choice of the parent JFrame using it's own window closing event, I wanted to see if the JPanel could be self aware of this on it's own.)

My hack works ... tell me what's wrong with it. It has to be wrong, even if it's functioning for me. Right?

The following snippet is a running mockup.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JPanelClosing extends JPanel {

    static JFrame frame; // This frame is only here for the mmockup ... what
                         // follows after would be part of your own custom JPanel.

    private boolean formClosing = false;
    private boolean filterEvent = true;

    public JPanelClosing() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                formPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void formPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                    

        // This is a hack I came up with. The JPanel fires two events when
        // used in a waiting input dialog of an unkown JFrame that hosts it.
        // When the JFrame DefaultCloseOperation is set to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE:
        // PropertyChangeEvent fires twice when it opens, and twice when it closes.

        // So, I filter out the two events to pick one, like using !valueIsAdjusting.
        // Then, I filter whether it's state one, opening, or state two, closing.
        // This is all kept track of using two field variables; filterEvent, and formClosing 

        // With DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, (on my machine) I get:
        // Form opened.
        // Form Closed.

        // (EXIT_ON_CLOSE and HIDE_ON_CLOSE will only produce 'Form opened')

        if (!filterEvent) {
            if ( formClosing ) {
                System.out.println("Form Closed.");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                formClosing = true;
                System.out.println("Form opened.");
            }
            filterEvent = true;
        } else { // end if value not adjusting
            filterEvent = false;
        }

    }

    public static void main (String args[] ) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame = new JFrame();
                final JPanel panel = new JPanelClosing();
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using an AncestorEvent?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into it. It says it can detect: ANCESTOR_REMOVED
An ancestor-component was removed from the hierarchy of visible objects (hidden) and is no longer being displayed. Maybe that will work. I'll play with it and post back if I find this works more formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no idea if this is the canonical way of doing things, but with an AncestorListener, you are notified if the main window that holds your component is set visible by the ancestorAdded method being called. When this happens, you can get the window ancestor via `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(...)` and then add whatever listeners you desire to this window. For example:

package pkg1;

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestClosing extends JPanel {
    public TestClosing() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));

        // addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> System.out.println(evt));

        addAncestorListener(new MyAncestorListener());
    }


    private class MyAncestorListener implements AncestorListener {

        @Override
        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent ae) {
            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TestClosing.this);
            if (window != null) {
                window.addWindowListener(new MyWindowListener());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent ae) {}

        @Override
        public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent ae) {}

    }

    private class MyWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO desired actions
            System.out.println("window closed");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO desired actions
            System.out.println("window closing");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestClosing mainPanel = new TestClosing();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Closing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I suppose a ComponentListener, reacting to `componentShown(ComponentEvent ce)` could also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with this. Obviously, just listening for a window closing event on the frame is the straightest choice. I just wondered if others knew of a way for a JPanel to do this while only making changes to it's own source. Your way produced results on my machine, and thanks for, like others, steering me to the AncestorEvent. Never used it before, and this will be my introduction.

Comment: Interesting feedback: your way, which I trust more, gets a similar result as mine in that only DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE causes a call to windowClosed along with windowClosing. HIDE and EXIT only trigger windowClosing, and never call windowClosed. Mine acted the same way, an addidtional behavior for only the DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE scenario. Makes sense ... Exit just leaves and Hide never leaves ... so both produce only closing'. But, Dispose does leave, and yet the system hasn't exited, so we get to see the closed event happen. But my hack acted the exact same way too. Interesting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* you want to do what you're doing?

For one, this code plainly does not work. On my system *"Form closed."* never prints.

Second, what I'm catching in the istener are `"layeredContainerLayer"` and `"ancestor"` property changes when the window opens. `"ancestor"` change is probably what you want, more or less, maybe?

But can you ensure only single `"layeredContainerLayer"` source event gets fired in that order, or that it occurs only once, or  that nothing else gets propagated, ever? Even if you dig deep enough to *really* understand what's happening, and in which order, still don't do that. It's an ugly hack.

Maybe implement something relying on `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)` and your own listeners notifying whoever wants to be notified of shutdown.

Comment: I know it's an ugly hack. That's why I asked for direction. I think I'll just add the window listeners. I figured if there was a way for a JPanel to reliably know this, that we'd see a call in the library for it. This is why I asked. I'll just go add window closing events to the frames and call a cleanup method on the panel. New requirement. Thanks for the advice.